# Why can't I set `balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0` in the same tx as `msg.sender.transfer()`

Tags: solidity, web3js

Using pretty much the same pattern as the `withdraw()` function in the first example of [Solidity Common Patterns](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/common-patterns.html)

Here is a simplified version of the contract I am testing with.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract Account {
  mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

  function deposit() public payable {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += msg.value;
  }

  function withdraw() public {
    uint256 amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
    msg.sender.transfer(amount);
  }
}
```

When I call the `withdraw()` function, the tx status is returned as `0x00` and none of the changes are applied.

It seems that `balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;` is the offending line.

**Setting `balanceOf` After `transfer()` Doesn't Work Either:**

```
function withdraw() public {
  uint256 amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
  msg.sender.transfer(amount);
  balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
}
```

**This Works:**

```
function withdraw() public {
  balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
}
```

**Setting Balance to Something Other Than Zero Works:**

```
function withdraw() public {
  uint256 amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
  balanceOf[msg.sender] = 2;
  msg.sender.transfer(amount);
}
```

Am I missing something here or is there a bug in the tools?

**What I'm using:**

- Ubuntu 16
- Truffle
- Ganache
- Web3js

Comment: Your code looks good and works fine for me. Please provide more detailed steps (ideally a repo with all the code necessary to reproduce the bug).

Comment: This code looks OK. I'd suspect a problem with the way you're testing it, which we can't see unless you post it. 

If it's really working when you set the balance to `2` but failing when you set it to `0`, make sure you're setting the gas limit for both cases; If you don't set a gas limit manually, whatever tool you're using will try to work it out with `estimateGas()`, but this can go wrong if your contract clears storage due to an edge case involving gas refunds.